# Django dump JSON data

Tags: json, ajax, django, post

I'm trying to enter a word and have it show up on page through ajax.  There something simple I'm missing...

So I'm sending the info like this with Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type:"POST",
data:{'word': word},
success: function(data){
       //do something 
}
});
```

and the information is getting into the view and saving into the DB.  The problem happens when I try to return the new word:

```
def add_word(request, lecture_id):
    l = get_object_or_404(Lecture, pk=lecture_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        #see if there is a value with p
        if request.POST.has_key('word') and request.POST['word'] != "":
            success = {}
            try:
                oldWord = l.post_set.get(word=request.POST['word'])
            except:
                newWord = l.post_set.create(word=request.POST['word'], count = 1)
                success = {'new': str(newWord.word), 'count': str(newWord.count)}
            else:
                oldWord.count += 1
                oldWord.save()
                success = {'old': str(oldWord.word), 'count': str(oldWord.count)}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(success), mimetype="application/javascript")
    return HttpResponse(reverse('post.views.lecture_display', args=(l.id,)))
```

Im getting a 500 error...

```
[13/Oct/2011 15:14:48] "POST /lecture/3/add HTTP/1.1" 500 66975
```

Comment: That 500 error is a traceback.  You should visit that URL in your browser to see what it is.

Comment: You'll have to post the whole view, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the traceback, my guess is that what's failing is [one of]:

```
# A) This path is not resolving correctly (see named-URLs in Django's docs)
reverse('post.views.lecture_display', args=(l.id,))

# B) This word has unicode data, which can't simply be passed to ``str``
str(oldWord.word)
```

Open the URL directly in your browser, and you'll get the default Django traceback, 500 view.

Comment: @captDaylight - what ended up being the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn debugging rather that a particular fix.

1. Try opening that url without post data, see if there's a syntax or a name error.
2. If the problem persists, use `ipdb` or `pudb` package, insert the following line in the view and analyze what happens inside your code:

   def myview(request, id):
       import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

Use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to see what the server outputs and what urls it opens. Also take a look at [Django Debug Toolbar](http://justcramer.com/2008/09/07/django-debug-toolbar/) and [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/). The debug toolbar can show you all the templates that were rendered and all the local variables. Werkzeug also gives you a debug shell in any place of the call stack right from the browser.